# Why do some Administrative Divisions fail to translate into Entities?

Tags: geographics, entity

I am trying to prime the following list into a database to run some geo-stats:

```
geostats = 
{{DateObject[{2013, 12, 5, 13, 47, 19.822}, "Instant","Gregorian", 10.], "VIC", -37.8004, 144.984, 100.},
{DateObject[{2013, 12, 5, 20, 44, 57.715}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 10.], "VIC", -36.9902, 144.063, 100.},
{DateObject[{2015, 3, 27, 15, 38, 46.051}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 10.], "NSW", -33.7495, 151.065, 60.},
{DateObject[{2015, 4, 29, 16, 05, 10.006}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 10.], "NSW", -33.8261, 151.199, 106.},
{DateObject[{2013, 6, 17, 20, 25, 34.948}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 10.], "SA", -34.9266, 138.512, 25.}, 
{DateObject[{2017, 7, 21, 20, 01, 42.497}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 10.], "VIC", -38.3296, 144.263, 10.},
{DateObject[{2016, 09, 25, 21, 27, 40.98}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 10.], "QLD", -27.4635, 152.98, 106.},
{DateObject[{2014, 10, 31, 15, 19, 59.965}, "Instant","Gregorian", 10.], "VIC", -37.9829, 145.065, 31.8}}
```

So I transform it as follows:

```
state[s_String] := Switch[s, "VIC", "Victoria", "NSW", "New South Wales", "SA",
    "South Australia", "QLD", "Queensland"];
geostats = geostats /. {s_, t_, u_, v_, w_} :> 
{s, Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {state[t], "Australia"}], GeoPosition[{u, v}], w}
```

The output shows that some States are successfully converted into Entities while others are not:

[image]

Can anyone help me convert all States into Entities? The geographic functions won't acknowledge "New South Wales" and "South Australia" :^(

Edit: I believe I found the solution: Composite Names should be written without spaces in between. The function `state[s_String]` should read

```
state[s_String] := Switch[s, "VIC", "Victoria", "NSW", "NewSouthWales",
    "SA", "SouthAustralia", "QLD", "Queensland"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, all [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity) canonical names are camel cased, so you need to use camel case for your strings. However, you could also make use of [`Interpreter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter) to find the appropriate canonical name:

```
Interpreter["AdministrativeDivision"]["New South Wales"]
Interpreter["AdministrativeDivision"]["South Australia"]
```

> Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewSouthWales", "Australia"}]
>
> Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"SouthAustralia", "Australia"}]

Another possibility is to use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>.

Comment: When I type `Interpreter...`, my output prints in interpreted format already. I don't get the "canonical" output as you do.

Comment: @ThadeuFreitasFilho When I copy the output to MSE (Mathematica StackExchange) you see the InputForm, not the interpreted form.