# How do I apply GeoRegionValuePlot to a grouped Dataset?

Tags: dataset, geographics

I have a database like the one under [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199553/why-do-some-administrative-divisions-fail-to-translate-into-entities) which I transform into a Dataset by applying

```
cols = {"DateTime", "State", "Coordinates", "Amount"};
geoDataSet = Dataset[AssociationThread[cols, #] & /@ geostats]
```

Naturally, the original dataset is much bigger and so some of the coordinates repeat themselves. Therefore, when I

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[#Coordinates -> #Amount &/@ geoDataSet]
```

the amounts for the coordinates that repeat do not plot. So I have tried to `GeoRegionValuePlot` the following

```
geoDataSet[GroupBy["Coordinates"],Total,"Amount"]
```

which fails because the structure of the Grouped dataset has changed so my `GeoRegionValuePlot` function no longer works.

Is there another way to group the dataset while maintaining the keys "Coordinates" and "Amount" in order to use `GeoRegionValuePlot`?

Or how do I apply `GeoRegionValuePlot` to the Grouped dataset?

Comment: I think I have found an answer on the first reply to the question under https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136422/assign-names-to-dataset-columns?rq=1


`Dataset[KeyValueMap[<|"char" -> #, "freq" -> #2|> &, data]]`, where `data` is my grouped set.

Comment: I also said that the amounts for repeating coordinates don't plot. It is false. It's just that one can only see the darkest colour, because it overshadows the lighter ones.